# Mac OS X vim colors mangled

Tags: macos, terminal, vim, color-scheme

Here's my setup

- Mac OS X 10.6
- VIM (default version that comes with OSX 10.6)
- rails.vim (installed in .vim/autoload)
- ir_black.vim (installed in .vim/colors)
- i have "colorscheme ir_black" and "syn on" in ~/.vimrc

Now when I go into terminal and edit a ruby file with vim my colors are messed up. There are only a few colors showing up and some text is even blinking. I'm wondering if there's a conflict between rails.vim syntax highlighting and the ir_black color scheme? Can anyone help me fix this? I would like to use the ir_black color scheme.

Comment: The general solution to something like this in linux is to install the appropriate terminal specifications (generally in a package like ncurses-term). It can also happen if your colorscheme is (carelessly) trying to use 256 colors when the terminal doesn't support it, I believe.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The Mac OSX Terminal.app **in Snow Leopard** does not support 256 colors, which is required for the ir_black theme (this is the theme I use).

Download and try something like iTerm.app ([http://iterm.sourceforge.net/](http://iterm.sourceforge.net)), and you shouldn't have a problem with colors.

Or you could use MacVim ([http://code.google.com/p/macvim/](http://code.google.com/p/macvim))

Edit: As of OSX 10.7 Lion, the built in Terminal.app now supports 256 colors. See the comment below by **Chris Page** for how to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a terminal command to see how many colors the current terminal supports? I googled but can't find anything.

Comment: I can't find one either. I did find `infocmp`, however, that reports 256 colors in Terminal.app, which is incorrect.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors. The most direct way to see the number of colors supported by the current terminfo ($TERM) is `tput colors`. @Bryan Ross, either you're using Lion or a custom terminfo is selected. Check **Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced > Declare terminal as**. This sets the value of $TERM (in fact, that's all it does). Prior to Lion the default value is xterm-color, which declares 8 colors as shown by `TERM=xterm-color tput colors`, although most programs seem to assume 16 are supported if 8 are.

Comment: I have the same issue with the Mac terminal on El Capitan. Even though it's configured to `xterm-256color`. I've also tried using that Base16-Shell fixer but that made no difference for me

Answer (score 3):

I've been using a nearly identical setup, except for vim, which I grab from Macports. A few years ago I found ir_black and loved it. I now use it for all vim sessions, Terminal.app, and TextMate. Getting it to work with Leopard, and then Snow Leopard was a tad hokey. But things have improved. Follow the instructions here, [Making Terminal.app look great in Snow Leopard](https://schacon.posterous.com/making-terminalapp-look-great-in-snow-leopard).

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors. So using SIMBL is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, ir_black requires 256 colors, which is not supported by Terminal on 10.6.x and earlier.

As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors and the default $TERM value is xterm-256colors. ir_black should work fine for you if you upgrade to Lion.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors.

Answer (score 1):

on testing which colors can be displayed in your terminal of choice:
i just found this perl script on vim.org which dumps a list of 256 colors your terminal could possibly display...
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1349

Answer (score 0):

I have been using iTerm and was shocked to find out Terminal.app doesn't support 256 colors!  I recommend Bryan's answer.

However, if you ever get in a bind like this, you can change $TERM to vt100 and vim won't try to use colors.  In bash (the default MacOSX shell) you set this with:

```
export TERM='vt100'
```

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors.

Answer (score 0):

I use ir_black in Terminal.app but in 16 color mode, and it looks great. If you really prefer 256 color, I recommend iTerm2. The settings allow you to have the terminal report itself as "xterm-256" which is what's needed to use 256 colors in Vim.

Check this website for the procedure:
http://kevin.colyar.net/2011/01/pretty-vim-color-schemes-in-iterm2

There is a ir_black-based Vim theme called tir_black which is better suited for 256 colors:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2777

Looks awesome!

iTerm2 also has loads of nifty features.

I hope this helps.

Comment: As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal now supports 256 colors.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Indeed my comment applies to Snow Leopard. Anyhow I hope some find it useful.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I was just trying to provide an update, since the answer is now different on Lion.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with iTerm and solved it by going to **Settings > Profile > Terminal > Report Terminal Type** and setting it to `xterm-256color`.